# How to check if SQLite database is locked

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios11

I have an app that makes quite a few calls to a local SQLite3 database and sometimes these calls happen very close together (from different areas of the app).  How can I check, before a call to the database is made, if the database is currently locked?

Ideally I would rewrite the app (which has grown far beyond its original scope) but won't have time in this iteration.

Comment: There's no use checking before (if that is possible), it still can get locked between the check and your next call.   Better would be to make your call, and handle possible exceptions, eg. retry a number of times and report an error after too much retries.

Comment: My current workaround is to keep trying (in a loop) until the database is no longer locked but wondered whether it would be better to check if DB is currently locked, if so, wait 1 second and try again.

Comment: Your test could be an "BEGIN IMMEDIATE", effectively starting a transaction.  Then you'd be sure you own the lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what to do in `objective-c`, but I have been using `sqlite3` with `c` from quite long time And I also faced same issue. I used below method.

1. use [busy_timeout](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) and keep it configurable.
2. use [busy_handler](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html) to keep retry for `n` number of time.

This two improvement works well for me, but I had observed some performance issue which i am able to handle via above configuration parameter. You need to do some trade of between fail-safe and performance.

Comment: Sounds like the kind of thing that could be what I'm after.  Shame the sqlite3 object doesn't have a 'currentStatus property or something.'

Comment: @Ryan, unfortunately no.

Comment: In the end this is pretty much what I did.  Adding a busy_timeout, effectively counting down a small number of seconds if the DB is busy before retrying.